# Installing dask-ml throws "Solving Environment" error

Tags: python, dask, dask-ml

I'm getting the following errors when trying to install dask-ml with conda. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
(env3) C:\>conda install -c conda-forge dask-ml
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions


(env3) C:\>
```

Comment: Please indicate your version of conda and python. It may depend on what is currently installed in your environment - perhaps try with a new environment. The empty output looks like a bug in conda.

Comment: (env3) C:\>conda -V
conda 4.9.2

(env3) C:\>python -V
Python 3.9.1

Comment: in a new environment works, the difference is the python version (newenv) C:\>python -V
Python 3.8.5 . Is there a workaround?

Comment: I suppose not everything has yet been built for py39

Comment: the problem was that inadvertently installing `pip` upgraded `python`, reverting that solved the problem.

Comment: Either you should answer your own question with a summary of these comments or, if you think it won't be useful for anyone, simply delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that inadvertently installing pip upgraded python to version 3.9.1 from 3.8.5, reverting that solved the problem.